# R: subset matched words

Tags: string, r, search, subset

Here,

```
a<-c("Look at the sky", "Sun is bright", "cloudy day")
b<-c("sky", "day")
```

I want to subset `a` based on `b`. My preferred answer is:

```
"Look at the sky", "cloudy day"
```

How to do this in R?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Option 1

You can match a against all terms in b with `sapply`

```
sapply(b, grepl, a)

       sky   day
[1,]  TRUE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE
```

Then you collapse all rows with `apply` and subset `a`.

```
a[apply(sapply(b, grepl, a), 1, any)]

[1] "Look at the sky" "cloudy day"
```

### Option 2

Create a combined regexp pattern

```
paste(b, collapse="|")

[1] "sky|day"
```

and grep with it

```
a[grepl(paste(b, collapse="|"), a)]

[1] "Look at the sky" "cloudy day"
```

Comment: +1 - nice answer. I believe that `pattern <- paste(b, collapse="|")` would suffice for option 2. No need to wrap the pattern in brackets. Another alternative for the grep is: `grep(pattern, a, value=T)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the string searching facilities form the [stringi](http://stringi.rexamine.com) package:

```
library(stringi)
a[sapply(a, function(ae) any(stri_detect_fixed(ae, b)))]
## [1] "Look at the sky" "cloudy day"
```

Here we detect whether each string in `a` contains any string in `b` as its subsequence.